# Run a php shell from an php exec on a site

Tags: php

I have a problem when i try to run this exec statement. The exec wont start the php shell file as i want it too.

I've tried using shell_exec but that wont work either. And when i try to echo out the returning array and var i get the var to "1" and an empty array.

Here is my code I'm trying to execute:

```
<?php
$user = $_GET['u'];
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['user'] === $user) {
    $sID = $_GET['si'];

    exec('php C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\r\\pages\\create-csgo-server3.php');

    echo 'Server is being created.<br>';
} else {
    echo 'Permission denied.';
}
?>
```

It says "Server is being created." but it wont run the exec correctly.

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\r\pages\create-csgo-server3.php
```

I tried putting this over into the cmd and it worked correctly.

Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: Cut your \\\\ down to \\ .

Comment: I can try, thank you!

Comment: I tried cutting them down, but it still dosent work. So that was not the problem

Comment: What does not work. Look in the web server log for errors.

Comment: Okay i will do that. The exec statement wont startup the php file i  specified it to.

Comment: And i do not get anything in my webserver logs.

Comment: I doubt that the path to php.exe is in the path for the webserver user `C:/path/to/php C:/xampp/htdocs/r/pages/create-csgo-server3.php`

Comment: Oh okay now i understand

Comment: @ZakThorCSGO when you run it in server console, it works?

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a duplicate, but while I'm searching; the webserver user (user that runs Apache or IIS, etc.) doesn't have the path to `php.exe` in its path environment variable, but you must as it works for your user in a terminal.  Always use full paths:

```
exec('C:/path/to/php C:/xampp/htdocs/r/pages/create-csgo-server3.php');
```